# Gradle Not resolving SNAPSHOT as timestamp

Tags: gradle, artifactory, snapshot

I am currently having a problem when publishing a Gradle build to a snapshot Artifactory repository where 'SNAPSHOT' is not being resolved to a timestamp. The jars can be found on the repo but are in the format of '1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' instead of e.g. '1.0.1-20180420.112216-1.jar'. This is causing problems when other builds depend on the project in question. We currently have Maven builds which are pushing to the same repo without any problems.

I am using the maven-publish and com.jfrog.artifactory plugins. It is worth mentioning that I don't have a lot of Gradle experience.

Relevant pieces from build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

artifactory {

  contextUrl = ${rep.url}
  publish {
      ext.systemProperties = System.getenv()
      println "Publishing using this user: ${systemProperties.artifactory_user}"
      println "Publishing to this repo: ${systemProperties.artifactory_repo}"
      repository {
         repoKey = "${systemProperties.artifactory_repo}"
         username = "${systemProperties.artifactory_user}"
         password = "${systemProperties.artifactory_password}"
         maven = true
      }
      defaults {
        publications('mavenJava')
      }
  }
}

publishing {
   publications {
      mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        from components.java
      }
   }
}
```

relevant from gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0.2-bin.zip
```

Environment variables come from Jenkins and are the same used in our maven builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you actually set your jar name in the code at all. The [Gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:publications) for the Maven Publishing plugin tells you how you can customize the publication identity of your artifact:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'org.gradle.sample' // Modify the artifact group
            artifactId 'project1-sample'// Modify the artifact name
            version '1.1'   // Modify the artifact version

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

If you are not overriding these values in the publishing closure as shown above, the default values of the [project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) are being used for naming the artifact which is defined by the `group` and `version` properties of your project. The default version value is `version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'` if you start a Gradle project from scratch in IntelliJ for example.

The following code should help you to resolve your issue:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            version 'your_time_stamp'

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I omitted that part of the build.gradle, but it is something like this
group = 'our.group.id'
version = '1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
I will try overriding it in the closure as per your first code block. In the second are you recommending I use Groovy code to generate the timestamp myself?

Comment: Yes, this is what i mean with 'your_time_stamp'. You have to replace it with a function to generate the timestamp.